# How to get updated files via gitpython?

Tags: gitpython

I'm trying to get the paths of all the changed files in this **current branch**, compared to **master**.
I've tried

```
repo = Repo("path/to/repo")
files_changed = [item.a_path for item in repo.index.diff("master").iter_change_type("D")]
for f in files_changed:
    print(f)
```

and I have few questions about the results:

1. When using `R` `iter_change_type` to get the files that are renamed, it only gives the new path. How do I get the original path of the file?
2. When using `D` `iter_change_type`, it gives all the files that are **added** instead of **deleted**. And `A` `iter_change_type` gives all the files that are **deleted** instead of **added**. Shouldn't this be the other way around?

Comment: The original path should be made available by the Python code, but how it goes about doing that, I have no idea. As for A-vs-D letter codes: this depends on the "direction" of the diff. You're diffing against the index, but consider what happens if we diff commit C1 vs commit C2. C1 has file F1 but not file F2; C2 has file F2 but not file F1. `diff C1 C2` says "delete F1, add new F2" and `diff C2 C1` says "delete F2, add new F1". So these are just mirror images.

Comment: @torek how do I change the code so that it compares current branch against master?

Comment: Get the current branch (however one does that) or use `HEAD`. Note that `HEAD` is a synonym for the current *commit*, so it works even when there's no current *branch* because HEAD is detached. The current *branch* is a name—a string starting with `refs/heads/`—and if that branch exists, it names a specific commit. The one case where the current branch doesn't exist is when you're in the "orphan branch" or "unborn branch" state, most commonly seen in a new, totally empty repository.

Comment: Note that when the current branch doesn't exist (but its name is stored in `HEAD`) a bunch of things don't work: for instance, you can't turn `HEAD` into a hash ID. That's why a lot of hosting sites will create an initial commit for you, so that you never have to deal with this weird state.

Comment: In *detached HEAD* mode—which is more common than unborn-branch mode—there's no *current branch* but there is a *current commit*. You get this with `git switch --detach` or `git checkout` of anything that is not a branch name, e.g., when checking out a tag or a historical commit. Git also uses this mode during `git rebase`, so in a conflicted rebase or when using `git rebase -i`, you will see it.

Comment: @torek Got it, by the way my script set up, `HEAD` should work. Do you know how to specify the branch to compare against to? in gitpython that is.

Comment: No, the last time I did any Git and Python work, I had to write my own Python code (for Python 2.3).